# PHP script will not recognize matching strings

Tags: php, forms, file

I am trying to write a php script that will scroll through a list of strings in a text file and compare each string to user input from an html form. 
If a match is found then the string the user entered should be posted to the screen. Somehow the comparison between the two strings never produces a match despite the presence of identical strings.

here is the php code

```
<?php
session_start();
$myFile = "usernamelist.txt";

if (isset($_POST['originaluserid'])){//verifies the creation user input from the html page(for users signing up for the first time)
    $userid = $_POST['originaluserid'] . PHP_EOL;
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");    
    fwrite($fh, $userid);
}

if(isset($_POST['userid'])){//verifies the existence of username information for an old user logging back in
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
}

$theData = fgets($fh);  

$_SESSION['id'] = $userid;//so that userid can be called in another page

if ($fh) {
    while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) {
        if($userid == $theData){//errors in matching input with collected data in text file
            echo "<html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
            <p>the ID of the user is: $userid</p> <!--I want userid to be displayed here-->
            <p>welcome to My Shopping Page</p>
            </body>
            </html>";
            exit;
        }
    }
    fclose($fh);
} else {
    echo "error";
    exit;
} 

echo "access not granted";
?>
```

here is the html code

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="myshopping.php" method="post">
Log in with User ID:
<input type="text" name="userid">
<br>
<input type="submit">
<br>
Sign up for a brand new account:
<input type="text" name="originaluserid">
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and all that is in the text file ("usernamelist.txt") is:

```
username1
username2
username3
username4
```

Comment: Actually there are some hidden characters in there, like newlines and carriage returns. `if($userid == trim($theData))`

Comment: This would be a lot easier with a DB.

Comment: In your loop, you're returning fgets into `$line`, but then checking `$userid` against `$theData`. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: He does `fgets` twice @Don'tPanic, but you're right - he should be using `$line` as that represent each line in turn during the loop. `trim($line)`

Answer (score 3):

Well first off you are using the variable `$theData` rather than the variable `$line`.  Also `fgets` doesn't strip white space characters including newlines so you'll need to use `trim`.  Try this and see if it works:

```
if (trim($userid) == trim($line)) {
```

You'll also need to remove `$theData = fgets($fh);` because it's fetching the first line and it won't be checked with the above logic.

Comment: Also need to remove the `$theData = fgets($fh);` or else it will never match the first name.

Comment: Good eye  `(';.;')`